CSS make an absolute positioned container´s width fit-content of its insides
I want to position a div with dynamic text and dynamic position inside a container. Placing the div is not a problem, but I expected it to adjust its width to its content and its size according to the parent container.
How can I make the green box auto fit its width to the length of the text inside of it?
(Size of the green box shall by dynamic based on the size of the outer box and the font size in the green box shall be dynamic based on the height of that green box.)
I made a jsfiddle for it here: https://jsfiddle.net/pdrasyoj/
<style>

.outerBox {
   container-type: size; 
   width: 400px; 
   height: 400px; 
   border:1px solid green;
   position: relative;
 }

.highlightBox {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #32db01;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #000;

  padding: 2.8cqh;
  height: 10cqh;
  width: fit-content;
  min-height: 30px;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2.5cqh; 
  right: 2.5cqh;
  container-type: size;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.dynamicText {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 80cqh;
  line-height: 80cqh;
}

</style>


<div class="outerBox">

<div class="highlightBox">
  <span class="dynamicText">
    dynamic button text
  </span>
</div>

<div>


why not use inline-block instead of setting the width?

@Tacoshy can you show me where you want it to be an inline-block element?

Here is a solution. The inner container was not able to receive its height and width from the dynamic text and so it could not inherit it to the container with the text that referred to it.
The solution was to use the outer container as reference and adjust the inner container´s font-size dynamically based on that outer containers values.


.outerBox {
   container-type: size; 
   width: 400px; 
   height: 400px; 
   border:1px solid green;
   position: relative;
 }

.highlightBox {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #32db01;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #000;

  padding: 2.8cqh;
  height: 10cqh;
  width: fit-content;
  min-height: 30px;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: max(2.5cqh, 5px); 
  right: max(2.5cqh, 5px);
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.dynamicText {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: max(8cqh, 20px);
  line-height: max(8cqh, 27px);
}
<div class="outerBox">

<div class="highlightBox">
  <span class="dynamicText">
    dynamic button text
  </span>
</div>

<div>




From the documentation on container-type:

Size containment turns off the ability of an element to get size
information from its contents, which is important for container
queries to avoid infinite loops.

Your code works fine without the container queries.


.outerBox {
   width: 400px; 
   height: 170px; 
   border: 1px solid green;
   position: relative;
 }

.highlightBox {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #32db01;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 0 #000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px; 
  right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dynamicText {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
<div class="outerBox">
  <div class="highlightBox">
    <span class="dynamicText">
      dynamic button text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>




Well, this works with the absolute values xou gave it, but not in the dynamic context I need it (based on parent container size). So unfortunatly, this does not solve the problem.

Perhaps you could edit your question to be more specific about your requirements, or more detailed.

yes, done. But I found a solution for the problem and posted an answer in the meantime..
